# Improper exception handling / object freeing probably causes memory leak (Cause: unnoticed "variable might not be assigned" warning)

Tags: web-services, delphi, dll, memory-leaks

### Full source of example with same problem

[Full source of example with same problem](http://pastebin.com/riBXenDa)

### Continuation with all code inside single EXE

I have moved everything to single EXE

```
var SenderInstance: AutoGeneratedWebserviceUnit.Sender;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SenderInstance := AutoGeneratedWebserviceUnit.GetSender(False, 'http://invalid_URL');   // => there is no exception here
end;

...


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  req: AutoGeneratedWebserviceUnit.Request;
  res: AutoGeneratedWebserviceUnit.Response;
begin
  try
    req := Request.Create;
    try
      with req do
      begin
        ID := 0;
        param := 'trash';
      end;
      res := SenderInstance.Request('Login', 'Pass', req);   // => ESOAPHTTPException + EAccesViolation !
      ShowMessage(res.status);
    finally
      req.Free;
      res.Free;   // ### MOST POSSIBLE PROBLEM CAUSE ###
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

I understand ESOAPHTTPException, **but AV? WHY?**...

### Problem

Strange things happens after raising ESOAPHTTPException...
**I suppose that there is something like a memory leak that I can't figure out or I did something really really stupid...**

Any settings? Maybe I forgot something?

### Clue

**I've found something
It's about "res.Free;" line inside try/finally block
Disabling this line causes no AV
But Assigned(req) returns True
Assigned(res) returns True too...**

What the....?

Comment: All of your casts are wrong. You are asking the compiler to treat those strings as being ANSI encoded but they are UTF-16 encoded. As for your problem, it's hard to say. I think debugging is probably needed. Only you can do so because we do not have an MCVE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Corrected. I mixed Delphi 5 code.

I moved everything from DLL to single EXE
Entering invalid WebService URL causes not only ESOAPHTTPException, but also AV...

Comment: As @DavidHeffernan said we can not tell why the `AccessViolation` is occurring without a complete example. If you can not provide it, you will need to debug and step into every procedure until you find the one causing the AV.

Comment: @GuillemVicens Bigger example

Comment: Still hard to say what is the cause as you do not show the unit generated from the `WSDL`. It seems obvious though that either `SenderInstance` is not really instantiated or the WSDL unit contains the source of the error.

Comment: @GuillemVicens SenderInstance is not really instantiated => It's MOST LIKELY.
How to check it properly? It seems that all connection stuff happens after calling SenderInstance methods. Am I right?

The problem is that I thought that I would get exception when I try to create instantion of Sender with invalid URL... But there is no exception generated!

How to properly check for valid instantiation of WebService stuff?

Comment: You need to debug and check if it is assigned.

Comment: @GuillemVicens
The problem is that Assigned(SenderInstance ) returns True despite invalid URL...
I added full sample on pastebin / tested on Delphi XE 7

Comment: Didn't the compiler warn you that `res` might not be assigned? It should have. Never ignore a compiler message.

Comment: @RobKennedy You are right - I haven't noticed... It's my fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem causing the AV lies in your `try..finally` clause in the `Button1Click` event handler.

You are trying to free your `res` variable (response), which has **not** been assigned anything yet, since the call to the `Request`method fails with an exception. This means it contains garbage and by calling `res.Free` you are accessing memory positions you should not, which can provoke almost any kind of strange error.

To solve it set res to `nil` before entering the `try..finally` and check if it is assigned before calling `res.Free`.

On a side note, this happens because `res` is a **local** variable. If it would be a **member** of an instance of a class the compiler would have assigned it a `nil` value automatically.

**UPDATE**

As @RobKennedy stated, it is much better to use *nested* `try..finally` blocks than assigning `nil` as I first told you (which can potentially lead to problems if some destructor fails).

So you would do something like following:

```
req := Request.Create;
try
  req.ID := 0;
  req.param := 'trash';

  res := SenderInstance.Request('Login', 'Pass', req); 
  try
    ShowMessage(res.status);
  finally
    res.Free;
  end;
finally
  req.Free;
end;
```

Comment: oooh......oO
**BINGO!**

Strange....
Sorry for my horrible tangled messy post

**GREAT THANKS for wasting your time for my stupid problem :]**

Comment: Don't check whether it's assigned before calling `Free`; such a check never yields any information. Instead of setting it to `nil` first, the more common solution is to use two `finally` blocks, one to protect `req` and one to protect `res`. Only enter the one for `res` *after* `res` has been acquired.

Comment: @RobKennedy, I agree it is safer to use _nested `try..finally` blocks. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @RobKennedy mhmmm.... Thanks for advice :) I was following a SOPA example from http://www.drbob42.com/examine/examinE2.htm and didn't checked it too much...